# Issue with AutoMapper having Unmapped properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ok, so first of all, what I am trying to do is get user details from Registration form in angular and register those details in to the SQL Server database. I have been following a couple of tutorials and I am wondering why is it that when I run the command to make a new migration it creates a table with a lot of different properties, I did not specify.

For example, by default it creates these properties:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "User",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                },
```

I do not know where these properties come from and I would like to know if I could change this. I have made one website following a tutorial, but now I am trying to experiment a new project on my own. So, the problem is that when using AutoMapper I get this error message, I would like to know how to solve this problem:

> AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be mapped using the current configuration.
>   AccountModel -> ApplicationUser (Destination member list)
>   UserWebAPI.Models.AccountModel -> UserWebAPI.Models.ApplicationUser (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties:
>   Id
>   NormalizedUserName
>   NormalizedEmail
>   EmailConfirmed
>   PasswordHash
>   SecurityStamp
>   ConcurrencyStamp
>   PhoneNumber
>   PhoneNumberConfirmed
>   TwoFactorEnabled
>   LockoutEnd
>   LockoutEnabled
>   AccessFailedCount

**AccountController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UserWebAPI.Models;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace UserWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController (IConfiguration config, 
            IMapper mapper,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _config = config;
        }

        [Route("api/User/Register", Name = "GetUser") ]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(AccountModel model) //add async Task<Result>
        {
            //var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext());
            var userStore = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);
            //var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var manager = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userStore, model.Password);
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            //var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            user.LastName = model.LastName;

            if (manager.Succeeded)
            {
                //IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, model.Password);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { id = userStore.Id }, user);
            }
            return BadRequest(manager.Errors);
        }

    }
}
```

**AccountModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class AccountModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> //DataContext instead of ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            //AspNetUsers -> User
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .ToTable("User");
            //AspNetRoles -> Role
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .ToTable("Role");
            //AspNetRoles -> UserRole
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserRole");
            //AspNetUserClaims -> UserClaim
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserClaim");
            //AspNetUserLogins -> UserLogin
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserLogin");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why is it that when I run the command to make a new migration it creates a table with a lot of different properties, I did not specify.

Since you `ApplicationUser` inherits the `IdentityUser`, when you do migration, it will create the table with those properties by default.You could press F12 to check the `IdentityUser` model in vs( see the `IdentityUser<string>` which it inherits).

Also refer to [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

MappingProfile.cs:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<AccountModel, ApplicationUser>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the issue, however having a new issue: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: password. I do not know if this is an angular issue or c# issue. I will probably have to ask a new question.